# Complexity of choose in R

Tags: r, combinations

To calculate "N choose K" (the binomial coefficient) in R, we use [`choose(n,k)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Special).

This function is implemented in [`src/nmath/choose.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/choose.c). For large `n` and `k` it calculates `floor(exp(lfastchoose(n, k)) + 0.5)`. Can anyone shed light on what this is?

Furthermore, what is the time complexity of `choose(n,k)`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation For the usual correct calculation you need k divisions an k multiplications if k<n/2. If k>=n/2, then you need (n-k) divisions and (n-k) multiplications.

Comment: thanks @jogo. what does lfastchoose calculate?

Comment: Refering to the name of the function it should calculate an approximation of `log(choose(n, k))`.